# Hide a Button with php

Tags: php, wordpress, button, hide

I have a button on my wordpress site which should not be visible for some users. I wrote a code in the functions.php but it seems that this does not work. I'm not sure if this is a possible reason:

```
<?php
function hide_button() {

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
?>

    <a href="link_that_should_hide" class="page-title-action aria-button-if-js" role="button" aria-expanded="false"

        <?php switch( $user_id ) {
            case X: 
                echo 'style="display:none"';
                break;

        }
        ?>
    
    >Datei hinzufügen</a>
<?php
}

add_filter('hide', 'hide_button');
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are making your own task way more complicated than what it is and not foolproof. Anyone can easily remove a `display:none` from a link. Just display the link or not based on `if($user_id != 24)`

Comment: Having that code in a [filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) also seems strange. Filters tend to get some argument, modify it if needed and then return it. This looks more like it should be some short code, or if it's only in one place and everything is hard coded, just put an if-statement in the template directly.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `in_array` so you can store the users that are not supposed to see the link easier.

```php
function hide_button()
{
    if (!in_array(get_current_user_id(), [24])) {
        ?>
      <a href="https://xn--werkstattrte-niedersachsen-phc.de/wp-admin/media-new.php"
         class="page-title-action aria-button-if-js" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Datei hinzufügen</a>
        <?php
    }
}

add_filter('hide', 'hide_button');
```

Changes from your original is to not even have the link be available (instead of only hidden from the browser), and to use `in_array` to allow you to keep adding user_id's as needed.